# Android Production Instant App not showing "Try Now" button in google playstore

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have uploaded an installable app and added an instant app in playstore. Everything went smooth. No errors. And moved both of that to production. But try now button is not enabled. Only thing I can able to see is Install button. Also my app link url is also leading to web not instant app. Can some one please help me out.

Comment: Have you Enabled instant app for your account to do that go to Settings>google>instant app and enable it and then try

Comment: Did you deploy to the instant production track? What's the package name?

Comment: Ya ya .. I have enabled in Google settings..and I deployed it in instant app production track only. It's also saying that instant app is live ..but try now is not coming for anyone. My app is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apps.vicky.devicehealth .

Comment: From your listing, I see that you've probably just uploaded all this, and I assume including the assetlinks.json? It will take a day or two for Google Play to sync up with you. Also, after downloading your full-installed app, I noticed that the "Open by default" doesn't yet say "Open in this app", so that means the url verification is not complete. Double check that `autoVerify` and `default-url` exists in both installed and instant app manifests.

Comment: Ya now the URL is working. Can able to access as Instant app. It is literally taking a day to reflect as instant app in play store. This time delay is not mentioned in any documentation I suppose. thanks guys.

Comment: @VickyCj Do you now have the "Try Now" button showing on the PlayStore?

Comment: @guillaume. Yup now I have

Comment: this button is only available on release, right?

Comment: Mine took a day to show the button "try now" when I published on Alpha after fixing the missing default-url.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Playstore will take nearly a day to reflect "try now" button in the play store for your instant app. Probably it's because it needs to index your url to all Google search engine servers.

Comment: It took them four days to show mine(!). Your response kept my hope alive.