# Try now option on playstore is not available and opening the link shows not found

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

thanks in advance

Just trying to make an dummy app with instant app functionality. Installable part just works fine and the instant app module is also getting launched from android studio, but when uploaded to play store try now option is not showing up and when the links for the instant app is opened in browser or tapped from chat application is shows not found. Followed google i/o video of converting an app to instant and code labs instructions and some other blogs and videos but not able to figure out where the problem lies.

[assetJson file link](https://anilsharma92.000webhostapp.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json)

Base Module : 
 gradle :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    baseFeature true

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    application project(":appmodule")
}
```

manifest :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.demo.anil.tictactoe">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--<meta-data android:name="asset_statements" android:resource="@string/asset_statements" />-->
        <!--<meta-data-->
            <!--android:name="default-url"-->
            <!--android:value="https://anilsharma92.000webhostapp.com/game" />-->

        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="default-url"
                android:value="https://anilsharma92.000webhostapp.com/game" />

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".GameActivity">
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:host="anilsharma92.000webhostapp.com" />
                <data android:pathPattern="/game" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ExtraActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:host="anilsharma92.000webhostapp.com" />
                <data android:pathPattern="/extra" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

app module :

manifest :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.demo.anil.appmodule">

    <!-- <application -->
    <!-- android:allowBackup="true" -->
    <!-- android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" -->
    <!-- android:label="@string/app_name" -->
    <!-- android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" -->
    <!-- android:supportsRtl="true" -->
    <!-- android:theme="@style/AppTheme" /> -->
    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >

        <meta-data android:name="asset_statements" android:resource="@string/asset_statements" />

        <!--<meta-data-->
            <!--android:name="default-url"-->
            <!--android:value="https://anilsharma92.000webhostapp.com/game" />-->

        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".FinishActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

gradle :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.demo.anil.appmodule"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':app-base')
}
```

instant app gradle :

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.instantapp'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 27
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":app-base")
}
```

full code available at : https://gitlab.com/jr.anilsharma/instant-app

Comment: Ok, I found your app in the PlayStore and I see the Try Now, but when I downloaded your app, how come the default-url I find shown is different than the one you posted here? `*.firebaseapp.com` Please check that out.

Comment: your original issue is probably this, might take a day or two to sync: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49397810/android-production-instant-app-not-showing-try-now-button-in-google-playstore or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50810112/instant-app-internal-test-behavior

Comment: issue was resolved it took two days to show up  and regarding firebase i updated the host url to firebase from 000webhost and thanks for your feedback  @TWL